# Hex viewer for Solaris (SunOS 5.11)

Tags: solaris, hex

Can anyone point me at a decent hex viewer for Solaris?  Looking for something with a front-end similar to bless on Ubuntu or Binary Viewer on Windows or ..almost the Delta Hex Editor Netbeans plugin.

This means:

1. Dual highlight of character vs. hex data.  (my cursor shows me where I am in both windows)
2. Conversion of data under cursor to various int/float types with little/big endian toggle.
3. Ability to edit data a bonus.

The Netbeans plugin is problematic because Netbeans is slow to start, and it doesn't satisfy criteria #1.  So I'm mostly using bvi at the moment.  X-Windows or console is fine.

edit: SunOS 5.11

Comment: You might get more responses on [softwarerecs.se]. I personally use `hexedit` from rigaux.org, but that doesn't meet your criterion #2. It's been a while since I've used it, but I feel like gHex might meet all 3?

Comment: Thanks @Fox.  I cross-posted the question over there.  gHex looks like it may be for newer distributions?  I couldn't find anything very easily.

Comment: [GHex](https://github.com/GNOME/ghex) is part of the GNOME project. The README says it should build on most unices, but I almost exclusively use CLI tools so haven't checked personally. It looks like it requires autotools to build

Comment: Thanks for the `GHex` link.  Probably obvious where to find that for some people, but not for me :)  Looks like gtk+-3.0 is required to build and not available in my package manager.  I could probably build Bless as easily :)  I'm surprised someone hasn't done a Curses hex editor with these features.  Would be crazy useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Midnight Commander** for this.

It is a very simple install in Solaris 11:

```
$ pkg install pkg:/file/mc
```

Now, to view/edit a file, just do:

```
$ mc -v foo.bar
```

This will 'show' the file. Now press <kbd>F2</kbd>. This will bring you in hex mode (still in view mode). Then pressing in <kbd>F2</kbd> will allow you to edit .. in hex mode.

In the example below I'm hex editing some random file:
[image: Midnight Commander Hex Edit]

As for conversion of int/float between little and big endian this is not something Midnight Commander can do, but there are a couple of free online tools for that. Here's [one example](http://www.scadacore.com/field-tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/).

Comment: Wow.  Serious MS-DOS flashbacks, here.  I feel like I had this installed on a Windows machine at one point.  Doesn't do #2, but I'm truly not sure anything exists that does at this point.  (Bar spending a LOT of time building packages from source)

Comment: @zzzyz. Your flashback is probably from an old PC tool called "Norton Commander". :-)

Comment: @zzzyz. Updated my answer wrt to endian conversion.

Comment: you may be right, but I think I may have used this tool.  I doubt I would've pirated or purchased Norton.  On the int/endian thing, it's a matter of convenience to be able to move through the bytes, examining the numbers under the cursor as they change, looking for sensible values.  Poorly documented files that are used across system architectures.  I probably need to see if there's a bless/scp solution I can just use from Linux.